# Generate aspx file one below other in single tab

Tags: asp.net, printing

I am having a complete `.aspx` page which contains header,footer,textbox,tables everything. Values in these all fields come from code behind `.cs` file.

For different set of data i am generating different `.aspx` page file in tabs. so that user can take print of it.

i was doing something like this to open multiple tabs

```
var cust_prop_id = $('#hdnPropertyNo').val().split(',');

$.each(cust_prop_id, function (i, val) {
var myWindow = window.open('UserInfo.aspx?Prop=' + val, '', '');
});
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

- All of sudden client said user wont go to each tab and say "Print".
- Instead generated all `.aspx` one below other in single tab. so in one single click user can able to print all generated .aspx files

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Is this is a very big page ?Other pages are small or big ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad It is kind of big page say 2 pages in length consisting of tables and textboxes and paragraphs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways here are two most common.

Method 1

Create user control for each page which you want to be printed add these user controls in the page where user will print the page.Load each user control in separate div and place in main container and at print time get css of container div which will include all data.

Method 2

Create div for each page which you were opening in new window  in a main container .Load data in divs at page load and when user press Print get all html of container div and print it.

Comment: `Create user control for each page` ??? No. Its only single page. i am just looping it with different set of data

Comment: As you have said that you open each tab on new page so i assumed it.Ok if this is a single page than you only need to put all data in one div and when user click Print button just print html of that div.